# Java How to change color of next circle

Tags: java, graphics

Here is code where you use mouseListener to create circles on a canvas. The color of the circles start at green. When you hold "R" and you click on the canvas, all the circles change to Red. When you hold "B", all the circles change to Blue. How do I make it so it keeps the colors of the previous circles so when I start off with green and make 3 circles, when I press R, the next circle I make is Red but the 3 previous circles stays green. Here is the code below.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
public class GraphicsEx extends JFrame {
    private Canvas theCanvas;
    public GraphicsEx() {
        super("The Window");
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(640, 480);
        theCanvas = new Canvas();
        theCanvas.addKeyListener(new ColorSelector(theCanvas));
        theCanvas.addMouseListener(new ClickToAddCircles(theCanvas));
        theCanvas.setFocusable(true);
        add(theCanvas);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphicsEx gdo = new GraphicsEx();

    }
}

class Canvas extends JPanel {
    private MouseEvent[] eventHistory;
    private static final int MAX_EVENTS = 1000;
    private static final int RADIUS = 100;
    private int totalEvents;
    private Color color;
    public Canvas() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        eventHistory = new MouseEvent[MAX_EVENTS];
        totalEvents = 0;
        color = Color.GREEN;
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("Hello...");
        int h = getHeight();
        int w = getWidth();

        g.setColor(color);
        for (int e = 0; e < totalEvents; e++) {
            g.fillOval(eventHistory[e].getX() - RADIUS /2, eventHistory[e].getY() - RADIUS /2, RADIUS, RADIUS);
        }
    }

    public void changeColor(Color newColor) {
        color = newColor;
    }
    public void addEvent(MouseEvent e) {
        eventHistory[totalEvents++] = e;
    }
}

class ClickToAddCircles implements MouseListener {
    private Canvas theCanvas;

    public ClickToAddCircles(Canvas theCanvas) {
        this.theCanvas = theCanvas;
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse was clicked.");
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse was pressed.");
        theCanvas.addEvent(e);
        theCanvas.repaint();
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}



class ColorSelector implements KeyListener {
    private Canvas theCanvas;

    public ColorSelector(Canvas theCanvas) {
        this.theCanvas = theCanvas;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key Event firing..");
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyChar()) {
            case 'r':
                theCanvas.changeColor(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 'g':
                theCanvas.changeColor(Color.GREEN);
                break;
            case 'b':
                theCanvas.changeColor(Color.BLUE);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You're woking in an Object Oriented langue.  The first thing you should do is define a "circle" object. This would contain the location (x/y) of the circle AND the color(s) needed to draw it.  Now, every time `mousePressed` is called, you can take the current color, the event location and create a `Circle `instance and put it in the `List`

Comment: @MadProgrammer For the circle object, the x,y of the circle is eventHistory[e].getX() - RADIUS /2 and eventHistory[e].getY() - RADIUS /2. How would I put that into the object "Circle".

Comment: `Circle.x = e.getX()` - it's just a Plain Old Java Object.  If you want to also carry the size, then you need to supply the properties

Comment: [This (newly asked question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74409536/why-does-this-program-only-display-the-last-graphic/74409654#74409654) demonstrates a basic starting concept

Comment: @MadProgrammer would this work? int x = e.getX(); int y  = e.getY(); and those two go under mousePressed. What would I do next?