# Why does this program only display the last graphic?

Tags: java, swing, panel, frame

Im using JPanel and JFrame to create a program that can draw lines and circles. The problem is that my program only redraws the last object added.

I have tried moving around the repaint. For some reason, when I directly draw shapes onto the graphic in paintComponent(), they show up and refresh each frame. However, I have methods inside of paintComponent that pass the graphic variable to elsewhere methods that draw to the graphic object, these are the shapes that do not show up.

Painter Class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Painter implements ActionListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    
    /**
     * 
     */

    Color temp = Color.RED;
    
    // 0 = line, 1 = circle
    int object = 0;
    
    PaintingPanel canvas;
    
    Point startPoint = new Point();
    Point endPoint = new Point();

    Painter() {
        
        //buttons
        JButton circleBut = new JButton();
        JButton lineBut = new JButton();
        
        //frame
        //close operation
        //resizes
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        
        //holder holds the information
        JPanel holder = new JPanel();
        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        holder.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        leftPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1)); // 3 by 1 grid

        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
        northPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2)); // 3 by 1 grid
        frame.add(holder);

        // circle and line buttons

        circleBut.setText("Circle");
        lineBut.setText("Line");
        northPanel.add(circleBut);
        northPanel.add(lineBut);
        circleBut.setActionCommand("1");
        lineBut.setActionCommand("0");

        //
        holder.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // red
        JButton redPaint = new JButton();
        redPaint.setBackground(Color.RED);
        redPaint.setOpaque(true);
        redPaint.setBorderPainted(false);
        leftPanel.add(redPaint);
        redPaint.setActionCommand("red");

        // green
        JButton greenPaint = new JButton();
        greenPaint.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        greenPaint.setOpaque(true);
        greenPaint.setBorderPainted(false);
        leftPanel.add(greenPaint);
        greenPaint.setActionCommand("green");

        // blue
        JButton bluePaint = new JButton();
        bluePaint.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        bluePaint.setOpaque(true);
        bluePaint.setBorderPainted(false);
        leftPanel.add(bluePaint);
        bluePaint.setActionCommand("blue");

        holder.add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        // still need to add painting panel to the CENTER panel
        
        canvas = new PaintingPanel();

        holder.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        circleBut.addActionListener(this);
        lineBut.addActionListener(this);
        redPaint.addActionListener(this);
        greenPaint.addActionListener(this);
        bluePaint.addActionListener(this);
        
        canvas.addMouseListener(this);
        //holder.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        // still need to add chat panel to the SOUTH panel
        
        
        frame.setContentPane(holder);
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("red")) {
            temp = Color.RED;
            System.out.println("received r");
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("green")) {
            temp = Color.GREEN;
            System.out.println("received g");
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("blue")) {
            temp = Color.BLUE;
            System.out.println("received b");
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("0")) {
            object = 0;
            System.out.println("received 0");
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("1")) {
            object = 1;
            System.out.println("received 1");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        startPoint.setLocation(e.getPoint());
        
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // and this one
        endPoint.setLocation(e.getPoint());
        
        if (object == 0) {
            canvas.addPrimitive(new Line(startPoint, endPoint, temp));          
        }
        
        if (object == 1){
            canvas.addPrimitive(new Circle(startPoint, endPoint, temp));            
        }
        
        canvas.repaint();
        
        
        
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Painter game1 = new Painter();

    }

    

}
```

PaintingPrimitives:
`

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;

public abstract class PaintingPrimitive{

    Color color;

    PaintingPrimitive(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    // This is an example of the Template Design Pattern

    // this is all invariant code
    public final void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        drawGeometry(g);
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    protected abstract void drawGeometry(Graphics g);

}
```

`Line Class:`

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Line extends PaintingPrimitive{
    Point startPoint = new Point();
    Point endPoint = new Point();

    public Line(Point start, Point end, Color c) {
        super(c);
        this.startPoint = start;
        this.endPoint = end;
    }
    

    public void drawGeometry(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("graw geo called");
        g.drawLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
        
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Line";
        
    }
}
```

`Painting Panel:`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;

public class PaintingPanel extends JPanel {

    ArrayList<PaintingPrimitive> primitives = new ArrayList<PaintingPrimitive>();

    PaintingPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void addPrimitive(PaintingPrimitive obj) {
        
        primitives.add(obj);
        this.repaint();

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // i'm confident that this is not painting to the right graphics
        
        for (PaintingPrimitive shape : primitives) {
            
            //g.dispose();
            
            //this line works. this line is drawn each time its updated. 
            g.drawLine(0,0,100,100);
            shape.draw(g);
        }
    }

}
```

`

Comment: Looks to me like all your primitives share the same start/end point.  In your mousePresseed/Released you need to create a new Point instance, otherwise you just keep undated the same point objects with new values. You can verify this by display the start/end point as you paint each object.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that was weird, until it wasn't.  Your problem basic centers around...

```
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        startPoint.setLocation(e.getPoint());

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // and this one
        endPoint.setLocation(e.getPoint());

        if (object == 0) {
            canvas.addPrimitive(new Line(startPoint, endPoint, temp));
        }
```

You create a single instance of `startPoint` and `endPoint` and simply update the `location` of each `Point`.  You then pass these to each primitive you create.  This means that each primitive is using the SAME instance of `startPoint` and `endPoint`.  So, each time you call `setLocation` ALL the primitives are been updated.

Instead, do something more like...

```
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        startPoint = new Point(e.getPoint());

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // and this one
        endPoint = new Point(e.getPoint());
```

And because I'm paranoid and don't trust any one, I'd probably also do...

```
public class Line extends PaintingPrimitive {
    Point startPoint = new Point();
    Point endPoint = new Point();

    public Line(Point start, Point end, Color c) {
        super(c);
        this.startPoint = new Point(start);
        this.endPoint = new Point(end);
    }
```

Just to be sure

Comment: Wow! I wouldn't have caught that in a million years. Thank you so much MadProgrammer. I owe you one.